# Change the variables in $Q(x,y,z)=(x-y+z-1)^2-2z+4$ to have $Q(f(u,v,w))=u^2+v$

Tags: geometry, polynomials, quadratics, affine-geometry, quadrics

I have a problem with this exercise. Initially, they gave me this polynom, and I had to complete the squares:

$$Q(x,y,z)=x^2-2xy+2xz+y^2-2yz+z^2-2x+2y-4z+5.$$

I've done it, and I've checked with maple (so it's correct). We have:

$$Q(x,y,z)=(x-y+z-1)^2-2z+4$$

Now, they say that I have to find an affine transformation to change the variables to have:

$$Q(f(u,v,w))=u^2+v.$$

So I thought that I could do

$$\begin{cases}
u=x-y+z-1\\v=-2z+4\\w=0
\end{cases}
$$

and solve this system for $\{x,y,z\}$. But obviously it doesn't have a solution.

I'd appreciate any hint, because I don't know how to do this change of variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Why set $w = 0$?  Set it so that the transformation has a solution.

Comment: @Macavity I tried different options but I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you means by

> But obviously it doesn't have a solution

You don't need to solve this system of equations.
You just find an affine transformation which is
$$\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1\\0&0&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}-1\\4\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
And it works.

Comment: Who is $f(u,v,w)$ then? The image of $f$ has to be in terms of $(u,v,w)$. If not, with your affine transformation, $Q$ is a polynom in $x,y,z$, and I need it to be $u^2+v$. The matrix $$
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1\\0&0&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

does not have an inverse, and that's where the problem reside.

Comment: But if you solve the system without matrix, directly from the equations. You can get answers like $x=u-1$,$y=-1/2v$,$z=-1/2v+2$. The matrix does also not have an inverse. What do you think?

Comment: how did you get this equations?

Comment: $v=-2z+4$, so $z=-1/2v+2$. Then $u=x-y-1/2v+1$. I choose to set $x=u-1$, so $y=-1/2v$.

Comment: last question, I promise. Why do you choose $x=u-1$?

Comment: Sorry, I just got that an affine transformation must be reversible. So I am totally wrong.